# i need to manually change the focus of the camera. manually means using a code

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, sdk, camera

i need to manually (using a code) change the focus of the camera.
actually i need to change the focus of logitech cam using a c++ program.
As my knowladge, there is no way to control camera using opencv. I heard about windows sdk allowed to change the focus of the camera using code. can anyone help me to do this?

Logitech camera have auto zooming option. i need to write a program to change the zoom by a code.

Thank you.
best regards

Comment: does your camera have some own SDK? maybe `VideoInput` library can change those parameters. http://www.muonics.net/school/spring05/videoInput/ with "manually" I guess you mean "programmatically"

Answer (score 0):

One way to go (at least on Linux) is Video for linux.

Open a cam with id dev_id as

```
cv::VideoCapture cap =  VideoCapture( dev_id+CV_CAP_V4L2);
```

Setting the focus can then be done:

```
/// turn of autofocus
struct v4l2_control ctrl;
ctrl.id = V4L2_CID_FOCUS_AUTO;
ctrl.value = 0;

int ret = ioctl(dev, VIDIOC_S_CTRL, &ctrl);
if (ret < 0) {
    printf("unable to disable AutoFocus %s (%d).\n",
           strerror(errno), errno);
    return false;
}

/// set focus manually
ctrl.id = V4L2_CID_FOCUS_ABSOLUTE;
ctrl.value = focus;

ret = ioctl(dev, VIDIOC_S_CTRL, &ctrl);
if (ret < 0) {
    printf("unable to set absolute Focus %s (%d).\n",
           strerror(errno), errno);
    return false;
```

This works perfectly with a L920.

Comment: Thank you very much for advice...i will go through this